# Where do AJAX requests in an MVC application enter the server side code initially?

Tags: ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

To keep it simple I have a feedback form on my website. Whether or not the following is best practice is moot as I'm interested in the way this works. The customer can fill out their name, email address and reason for feedback on the form. This is then posted via AJAX to a server side function called SendFeedback. I am using .NET MVC4 and the SendFeedback method simply returns a true or false string. However I was testing out sending scripts through it to check out the security of the form and noticed that when I attempted to send through HTML tags or javascript that the SendFeedback method wasn't being invoked at all and instead my custom error page was being sent back to the client side AJAX response (if I sent though standard text, the SendFeedback method was being invoked as expected). Where is the first place that AJAX data is sent before it is passed into the server side method I am calling from the client? Is there any way to set a breakpoint here so I can examine what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of an ASP.NET feature called request validaiton which is turned on by default. And which executes in ASP.NET handler before your code. If you desire, this feature can be turned off in web.config, but I would strongly advise against it.

More information on request validation can be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No I do not wish to turn it off, merely know how it works.